# Create pandas freq string from floating point seconds

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to create a range of dates in pandas like:

```
d = pd.date_range('2014-02-03 00:00:00','2014-02-03 01:00:00', freq=freq)
```

where `freq` is a number in seconds.  If `freq` is an integer then:

```
d = pd.date_range('2014-02-03 00:00:00','2014-02-03 01:00:00', freq=f"{freq}s")
```

works.  If it's floating point, then in principle some combination of offset aliases can be used (e.g., '60S100L' for 60.1 seconds).
Is there a way to automatically generate the correct offset alias string from a floating point frequency?

For example, when the frequency equals 60.1 seconds, I wonder if there's a built-in method to transform the floating point number 60.1 to '60S100L' in order to obtain:

```
pd.date_range('2014-02-03 00:00:00','2014-02-03 0:03:00', freq='60s100L')
```

which yields:

```
DatetimeIndex([       '2014-02-03 00:00:00', '2014-02-03 00:01:00.100000',
               '2014-02-03 00:02:00.200000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='60100L')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basing on freq - argument

```
import pandas as pd

seconds = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq = 'S')
days = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018')
weeks = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='w')
monthsStart = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='MS')
quarters = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='Q')
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand how this answers my question...

Comment: Can U provide - expected output?

Comment: there is also - .asfreq function in pandas - there is possible to use eg like: df.asfreq(freq='30S'). Not sure it's resolve Your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function that wraps `pd.date_range` and handles the float/int conversions like so:

```py
def custom_daterange(start, stop, freq):
    # handle floats that can be ints (e.g. 60.0, 61.0)
    if freq == int(freq):
        freq = int(freq)

    if isinstance(freq, int):
        freq_str = f"{freq}s"

    elif isinstance(freq, float):
        freq_base = int(freq)
        freq_remainder = freq - freq_base
        freq_str = f"{freq_base}s{freq_remainder * 1000:.0f}L"

    else:
        raise ValueError("freq MUST be either int or float")
    return pd.date_range(start, stop, freq=freq_str)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> custom_daterange('2014-02-03 00:00:00','2014-02-03 01:00:00', freq=60)
DatetimeIndex([
    '2014-02-03 00:00:00', 
    '2014-02-03 00:01:00',
    ...
    '2014-02-03 00:59:00',
    '2014-02-03 01:00:00'],
    dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='60S'
)

>>> custom_daterange('2014-02-03 00:00:00','2014-02-03 01:00:00', freq=60.1)
DatetimeIndex([
    '2014-02-03 00:00:00', 
    '2014-02-03 00:01:00.100000', 
    ...
    '2014-02-03 00:58:05.800000',
    '2014-02-03 00:59:05.900000'],
    dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='60100L'
)
```

Comment: True, but this is limited to an integer number of milliseconds, no?

Comment: Suppose I could convert to nanoseconds and use this method for finer control...

Comment: You could, but also be aware that floating point numbers to have different rounding behavior than true decimals and can lead to issues. For the milliseconds I circumvented this issue since rounding errors usually won't effect these larger decimal positions by stripping away the smaller (above thousandths decimal place).